# Average position in the Morse potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, potential, molecules

Does anyone know the analytical expression for $\langleψ_n|x|ψ_n\rangle$ in the [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential)?

In other words, I'd like to find the average position of a particle at the $n$-th vibrational level in a Morse well.

Comment: If you're just looking for the expression, it's readily available on the Wikipedia entry. If you're looking for more, please edit your question with additional information.

Comment: @KyleKanos It gives the matrix element for $m>n$.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/zna.1987.42.issue-5/zna-1987-0505/zna-1987-0505.pdf) has the result for $n=0$.

Comment: [This paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.446165) might be relevant. I can’t tell because it is behind a paywall.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks! The second paper has serial expansions to calculate it with not-so-bad accuracy. I'll try to make it looking good and then put here as an answer. The first paper is also nice to have, since it's the simple expression which covers the most important case.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no analytical expression for arbitrary *n*.
As @G.Smith pointed out, the paper of Tipping R. H. and Ogilvie J. F., "Expectation values for Morse oscillators", The Journal of Chemical Physics **79**, 2537-2540 (1983) https://doi.org/10.1063/1.446165 gives a serial expansions for *n* <= 8, but they look quite bulky and one should be in *real* need of analytical expressions to use this in practice.